# How to convert a string timestamp into an array in Lua (or other languages)

Tags: lua, timestamp

I'm having this problem for a while and I can't find a good way to resolve it. So I have a timestamp like this for example : `local t = "00:00:0.031"` and I'm trying to convert it into an array like this :

```lua
local ft = {
    hours = 0,
    minutes = 0,
    seconds = 0,
    milliseconds = 31
}
```

This is pretty much the same no matter the language so if you have an idea on how to solve this but don't know Lua you can submit your answer anyway in any language. I tried solving it myself using regex and I'm quite sure it's possible this way...

Thank you for the interest to my question, have a good day (:

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a not bad way using `string.gmatch` which is splitting by regex in Lua. Here the value is being split by either `":"` or `"."`. Then there is a counter in place to match the index for the resulting table.

```
local t = "00:00:0.031"

local ft = {
  hours = 0,
  minutes = 0,
  seconds = 0,
  milliseconds = 0
}
local count = 1
for str in string.gmatch(t, "([^:|.]+)") do
  ft[count] = tonumber(str)
  count = count + 1
end
```

You can do a printing loop afterwards to check the results

```
for i = 1, 4 do
  print(ft[i])
end
```

Output:

```
0
0
0
31
```

The main problem I have found with my solution is that it does not save the values under the keys listed but instead the numbers 1 2 3 4.

Comment: there are no regular expressions in Lua.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `string.match` to extract the substrings in a first place. In a second time, you could use the function `tonumber` to convert it into numbers.

```
function ParseTimestampString (TimestampString)
  local Hours, Minutes, Seconds, Milliseconds = string.match(TimestampString, "(%d+)%:(%d+)%:(%d+)%.(%d+)")
  local Result
  
  if Hours and Minutes and Seconds and Milliseconds then
    Result = {
      hours        = tonumber(Hours),
      minutes      = tonumber(Minutes),
      seconds      = tonumber(Seconds),
      milliseconds = tonumber(Milliseconds)
    }
  end

  return Result
end
```

With the following code, you could get the results you want:

```
Result = ParseTimestampString("00:00:0.031")

print(Result.hours)
print(Result.minutes)
print(Result.seconds)
print(Result.milliseconds)
```

This should returns:

```
> Result = ParseTimestampString("00:00:0.031")
>
> print(Result.hours)
0
> print(Result.minutes)
0
> print(Result.seconds)
0
> print(Result.milliseconds)
31
```

Comment: It works really nicely, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My Simplest Answer Will Be Just Split the given string by your regex, in This Case For HOUR:MIN:SEC.MS
first Split By (:) To Get HOUR MIN & SEC+MS, Then Split SEC+MS by (.) To separate Both seconds And milliseconds

Below is my answer in java

```
import java.util.*;

class timeX {
    long hours = 0,
    minutes = 0,
    seconds = 0,
    milliseconds = 31;
    
    //Convert Given Time String To Vars
    timeX(String input) {
        //Split Input By (:) For Hour, Minutes & Seconds+Miliseconds
        String[] splitted=input.split(":");
        this.hours=Long.parseLong(splitted[0]);
        this.minutes=Long.parseLong(splitted[1]);
        
        //Split Again For Seconds And Miliseconds By (.)
        String[] splittedMandS=splitted[2].split("\\.");
        this.seconds=Long.parseLong(splittedMandS[0]);
        this.milliseconds=Long.parseLong(splittedMandS[1]);
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        timeX tmp = new timeX("30:20:2.031");
        System.out.println("H: "+tmp.hours+" M: "+tmp.minutes+" S: "+tmp.seconds+" MS: "+tmp.milliseconds);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Lua you can do...

The `os.date()` can be a format tool for seconds.
...but depends on Operating System.
This works on Linux but not (as i know so far) on MS-Windows.

```
print(os.date('%H:%M:%S',0-3600)) -- puts out: 00:00:00
print(os.date('%H:%M:%S',300-3600)) -- puts out: 00:05:00
```

Also it can output the date/time as a table.

```
> tshow=function(tab) for k,v in pairs(tab) do print(k,'=',v) end end
> tshow(os.date('*t'))
day =   4
year    =   2021
month   =   11
hour    =   11
yday    =   308
isdst   =   false
min =   23
wday    =   5
sec =   51
```

...and unfortunally it has no milliseconds.

If the table output of `os.date()` is saved as a table...

```
> ttable=os.date('*t')
> os.time(ttable)
1636021672
> os.date(_,os.time(ttable))
Thu Nov  4 11:27:52 2021
> os.date('%H:%M:%S',os.time(ttable))
11:27:52
```

...then its key/value pairs can be used for: `os.time()`

Further code do nearly what you expect when in `ttable` key 1 is your time with milliseconds as a string...

```
local tshow=function(tab) for k,v in pairs(tab) do print(k,'=',v) end end
local ttable=os.date('*t') -- Create a time table
ttable[1]='0:0:0.31' -- Numbered keys in sequence are ignored by os.tim()
ttable[2]=ttable[1]:gsub('(%d+):(%d+):(%d+)[.](%d+)','return {year=ttable.year,month=ttable.month,day=ttable.day,hour=%1,min=%2,sec=%3,milliseconds=%4}')
-- That creates ttable[2] with the value:
--- return {year=ttable.year,month=ttable.month,day=ttable.day,hour=0,min=0,sec=0,milliseconds=31}
-- Lets convert it now to a table with...
ttable[2]=load(ttable[2])()
-- Using tshow() to look inside
tshow(ttable[2])
```

That will output...

```
milliseconds    =   31
day =   4
year    =   2021
hour    =   0
month   =   11
min =   0
sec =   0
```

And this will put it out formated with `os.date()`

```
print(os.date('%H:%M:%S.'..ttable[2].milliseconds,os.time(ttable[2])))
-- Output: 00:00:00.31
```